# Неправильные аргумент std::map

Tags: c++, qt, map

Внутри класса используется карта:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, typename Arc> > graph;
```

При попытке сборки получаю:

- template argument 2 is invaid
- template argument 4 is invaid
- template argument 2 is invaid

Где Arc - класс определённый следующим образом:

```
class Arc {
private:
    unsigned capacity;
    unsigned flow;

public:
    Arc(unsigned _flow = 0, unsigned _capacity = 0);
    virtual ~Arc();

    unsigned getCapacity() const;
    unsigned getFlow() const;
    void setCapacity(unsigned _capacity);
    void setFlow(unsigned _flow);
    bool operator==(const Arc &arc) const;
};
```

[image: Может быть полезно]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите это `typename`, оно тут ни к чему:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


class Arc {
private:
    unsigned capacity;
    unsigned flow;

public:
    Arc(unsigned _flow = 0, unsigned _capacity = 0) {};
    virtual ~Arc() {};

    unsigned getCapacity() const;
    unsigned getFlow() const;
    void setCapacity(unsigned _capacity);
    void setFlow(unsigned _flow);
    bool operator==(const Arc &arc) const;
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    map<string, map<string, Arc> > graph;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/Gxzaae

Comment: Ошибка:
    type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 
    'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class 
    std::map'
         std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Arc> > graph;
                                                        ^

Comment: Как мне этого добиться? :) Чем вы вообще компилируете?

Comment: Знать бы :D Вообще Qt Creator 5.10, MinGW'шный g++, в проекте добавлено использование 11 стандарта. Перезагрузиться, что ли...

Comment: @ProstoNekitos: Если это ошибка из *вашей* версии кода, значит вы там наопределяли еще каких-то `Arc`, которые мешают. То есть вы нам тут рассказываете про некий класс `Arc`, а сообщение об ошибке четко говорит, что на самом деле в вашем контексте у вас `Arc` никакой не класс, а что-то совсем другое.

Comment: @AnT проект не мой: https://github.com/jexhson/streamz
Прошёлся по исходникам - нет ничего с таким же названием

Comment: @ProstoNekitos: Ну уберите ваш `graph`, а вместо него напишите там `Arc aaa;` и посмотрите, что вам скажет компилятор.

Comment: @AnT да, вы правы, не распознаёт как тип, но между тем при щелчке переходит именно на определение класса

Comment: @AnT  Автозаменой изменил имя во всех исходниках - заработало. Но я так и не смог найти ничего похожего на Arc ни среди функций, ни других переменных.